# Subpanel field visibility in SugarCRM 7.x

Tags: sugarcrm

I've created a custom module with 8 fields, but the subpanel just shows the 3 most important.  So how can I access the values in the other fields using a sidecar custom js file

I have created a custom subpanel-list.php view with subpanel-list.js but if I use model->get('name') it iwll only return the value if the field "name" is inside the subpanel-list.php viewdef array. If not I get "undefined".

My question is, how can I get ALL the fields from the selected row of the module inside my subpanel-list.js?

Comment: Sidecar only loads the fields necessary for the view.  Other than adding the additional fields to the subpanel, I think (but can't remember for certain) that there's a property you can specify which fields to load.  Alternatively fetch the full model in your js view and perform your actions when it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps: 
**1.** Just go to studio . 
**2.** Select module in which your subpanel is visible .
**3.** Click on Subpanel and just drag and drop remaining fields you want to show.